# Terminology for sequences/functions that approach each other

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

What do I call two sequences $a, b$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n - b_n| = 0$?  Or what do I call two functions $f, g$ such that $\lim_{x\to c} |f(x) - g(x)| = 0$?  (For my purposes, these are essentially the same thing, and I will happily extend a term for one to the other.)

This seems like such a straightforward condition that it must have a standard term, but I can't find it (in either context).  I looked through the Wikipedia article on all of the variations of big-$O$ and the like, but these are all too weak.  If $\lim_n a_n$ (hence $\lim_n b_n$) existed, then I could call $a$ and $b$ ‘coterminal’, but that limit might not exist.  In an incomplete space, I have seen $a$ and $b$ called ‘co-Cauchy’ under the weaker assumption that one (hence both) is Cauchy, but I don't want to assume that either.  I could call $\exp f$ and $\exp g$ ‘asymptotic’ (as $x \to c$), but I want to refer to $f$ and $g$ directly.

Surely somebody knows a term for this?

Comment: They are called equivalent. I am half-joking half-serious.

Comment: How about "asymptotically equal/equivalent"? The only problem with this term would be that you can pose a similar condition on the ratio and will then need another name for it :-)

Comment: I have the feeling that ‘asymptotic’ *should* mean what I want, but when I look it up, it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say $ a $ and $ b $ are mutually asymptotic. Example: "Since $ n -1/n$ and $n+1/n $ are mutually asymptotic. .." And usually even drop the word "mutually".

Comment: My understanding of the accepted meaning of ‘asymptotic’ would also allow one to say that $n - 1$ and $n + 1$ are mutually aysmptotic (which I take to mean that each is asymptotic to the other), but these don't meet my requirement.  That is why I'm searching for another term.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of asymptotes in calculus. Y=1/x has y=0 as asymptote but not y=1.

Comment: True, that does fit what I want.

Comment: I still hold out hope that there might be a better answer?

Comment: I'm still using ‘asymptotic’ at [the nLab page on uniform convergence spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/uniform+convergence+space), so I guess that I'd better accept this answer.